# Spring data MongoDB stop stream watch with no error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-webflux

I have a stream watching my collection that I would like to stop after few seconds.
I'm able to stop it however its always throwing me an error.

This is my stream :

```
ChangeStreamOptions options = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
            .filter(newAggregation(Job.class, match(where("operationType").in("insert"))))
            .build();

    Flux<ChangeStreamEvent<Job>> jobs = reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("jobs", options, Job.class);

    jobs
       .doOnNext(x -> {
      log.info("Notif body received={}", x.getBody());
    })
       .doOnCancel(() -> {
            log.info("cancelling consuming...");})
       .take(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .subscribe()

;
```

The ligne `.take(Duration.ofSeconds(10))` makes the stream stop as expected.

Ten seconds after the last notification received, the stream stops but an error is thrown :

```
2021-06-30 19:21:03.448  INFO 51694 --- [     parallel-1] c.p.c.JobChangeStreamService             : cancelling consuming...
2021-06-30 19:21:04.339 ERROR 51694 --- [       Thread-8] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Callback onResult call produced an error

com.mongodb.MongoException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.MongoException.fromThrowableNonNull(MongoException.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.onError(AbstractSubscription.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:97) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:89) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$3.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$3.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$4.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:168) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$4.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:331) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:310) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:242) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:467) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:111) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:401) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:376) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:677) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:644) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:514) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:511) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:220) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$AsynchronousSocketChannelAdapter.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:137) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:511) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1000(InternalStreamConnection.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:634) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:619) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:514) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:511) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:220) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:443) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:215) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.session.BaseClientSessionImpl.advanceOperationTime(BaseClientSessionImpl.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.session.ClientSessionContext.advanceOperationTime(ClientSessionContext.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.advanceOperationTime(ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.updateSessionContext(InternalStreamConnection.java:537) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$800(InternalStreamConnection.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:385) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how to avoid this error to be triggered ? Is it another way to stop this stream ?

Thanks !

Comment: `I'm able to stop it` please update with how you are stoping it.

Comment: the ```.take(Duration.ofSeconds(10))```makes the watch stop, I also tried ```.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))```, However the error above is always thrown

Comment: i dont understand, `take` does not "stop" anything, the documentation for take is `Take only the first N values from this Flux, if available. If n is zero, the source is subscribed to but immediately cancelled, then the operator completes.` So it takes 10 items from the flux if there is 10 items, if there is none items it will cancel, so it will abruptly end the connection to the database and the database will throw that error. To disconnect from a database you must close the connection with for instance calling `MongoClient.close()` to properly close the connection and free the resources.

Comment: My bad, I was using a bad way to stop the watch. timeout() is a better solution I think.
So should I close the connection inside my doOnCancel ?

Comment: that is one way to do it, if that is your intention.